# Android Studio Firebase "No Such instance field" error

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Firebase for my Android app. In the code below,

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
matchReference = rootReference.child("tournaments");
userReference = rootReference.child("Users").child(deviceID);

    userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                if(snapshot.child(matchList.get(position).getId()).exists()) {

                    //If the user has Starred this game

                    isStarred = true;

                } else { isStarred = false; }
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

I get a `"No Such instance field"` error in the `userReference` field. When I debug it, it gives me the correct database path, but it does not enters the `addValueEventListener` function.

My database looks like

[image]

and another child called "starredGames" will be added in my code.

Why is it giving me the error?

Comment: Is your `userReference` supposed to be a child of your `matchReference` rather than the `rootReference`? Can you show your Firebase structure in more detail please

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of getting the value of your `deviceID` is:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference deviceIDRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("6610609cfc2c7945");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String deviceID = dataSnapshot.child("deviceID").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", deviceID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
deviceIDRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```